# Let X ∼ exp (λ) and let a> 0. Calculate the expectation and variance of Y = min {X, a}.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let X ∼ exp (λ) and let a> 0.
Calculate the expectation and variance of   Y = min {X, a}.

> where if X ∼ exp (λ), that is, if P (X ≤ x) = 1 - e − λx

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is one way to set it up:

As Y takes on two values, use indicator functions to choose its values.
$\displaystyle Y=X\cdot\textbf 1_{X<a}+a\cdot \textbf 1_{X\ge a}$

The indicator functions determine the limits of integration.$\displaystyle E(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot\textbf 1_{x<a}f_X(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^\infty a\cdot \textbf 1_{x\ge a} f_X(x)dx=\int_0^a xf_X(x)dx+a\int_a^\infty f_X(x)dx$

Use the standard formula for variance. $\displaystyle var(Y)=E(Y^2)-(E(Y))^2$

The indicator variables cancel each other out in the cross term. $\displaystyle Y^2=X^2\cdot\textbf 1_{X<a}+a^2\cdot \textbf 1_{X\ge a}$

The only issue is that you have to do a lot of integration by parts

Answer (score 0):

$Z=\min(x,a)=\dfrac{(x+a)-|x-a|}{2}$

$Z = \begin{cases}\dfrac{(x+a)-(x-a)}{2}=a; & x>a\\\dfrac{(x+a)+(x-a)}{2}=x;& x<a \end{cases}$

$E(Z)$ is?